# id array member instance under ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I want to write something like this:

```
@interface Foo{

    __strong id idArray[]; 

}
@end
```

But the compiler complains about it:

```
Field has incomplete type '__strong id []'.
```

How can I create an id array member instance under ARC? And how do I init that array?
Using malloc? new[]?

I don't want to use NSArray because I'm converting a large library to ARC and that will cause a lot of work.

Comment: Why do you convert an already-working library to ARC? ARC is a per-file technology.

Comment: How big is this library, really? Is it worth the hassle of dealing with C arrays and boxing/unboxing to work with the rest of your program? Most existing users won't particularly mind a conversion process on first launch (heck, Mail does that); new users won't have anything to convert. And you shouldn't be storing a large array into RAM either…

Comment: Hi Yuji and Inspire48, Actually, the library is not an traditional library, it's https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc. The library will generate objective c source files based on *.proto files. And the generated *.m files will be included in my project directly, which is using ARC. I've tried using NSArray, but came up with tons of compile errors and cost me a whole day to fix that.So maybe the simplest way is to use id[].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to allocate dynamically the array, use pointer type of id __strong.

```
@interface Foo
{
    id __strong *idArray;
}
@end
```

Allocate the array using calloc. id __strong must be intialized with zero.

```
idArray = (id __strong *)calloc(sizeof(id), entries);
```

When you are done, you must set nil to the entries of the array, and free.

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
    idArray[i] = nil;
free(idArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Kazuki Sakamoto, it works! But the params passing to calloc seems to be like this:

Comment: Oh, I fixed the 1st param for calloc.

Comment: Thanks for actually providing a useful and correct answer, rather than asking why. I just ran into this for new code, and was glad for the help.

Comment: It's worth noting that zeroing the array (with calloc, bzero, memset, etc.) up front is critical, or ARC will try to release garbage non-zero values when you assign a value. (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9119631/120292 for details.) Also, failing to nil out all values before freeing the array will result in a leak.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an array size, e.g.:

```
__strong id idArray[20];
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you give the array a fixed size:

```
__strong id idArray[20];
```

or you use a pointer and malloc:

```
__strong id *idArray;

...

self.idArray = calloc(sizeof(id), num);
```