# ARC & Malloc: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, c, malloc, automatic-ref-counting, realloc

I have been working on a project for some time now, and I decided to make the jump to ARC.
I came across some code that was bombing out every time, and I would like to know why. I have managed to simplify it down to this snippet:

```
typedef __strong id MYID;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    MYID *arr = (MYID *) malloc(sizeof(MYID) * 4);

    arr[0] = @"A";     // always get an EXEC_BAD ACCESS HERE
    arr[1] = @"Test";
    arr[2] = @"Array";
    arr[3] = @"For";

    // uh oh, we need more memory
    MYID *tmpArray = (MYID *) realloc(arr, sizeof(MYID) * 8);
    assert(tmpArray != NULL);

    arr = tmpArray;

    arr[4] = @"StackOverflow";  // in my actual project, the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS occurs here
    arr[5] = @"Is";
    arr[6] = @"This";
    arr[7] = @"Working?";

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is happening here, tired this in 4 different projects, and they all fail. Is there something wrong with my `malloc` call? Sometimes it returns null, and other times it returns a pointer that I can't access.

Comment: Why the typedef? Object pointers that are not otherwise-qualified are assumed to be `__strong`.

Comment: Because in the actual project, `MYID` is a part of a struct (cocos2d's ccCArray). Also, the code will not compile without a qualifier for ownership, because it isn't part of a selector where the owner could be 'self'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "because it isn't part of a selector where the owner could be 'self'". The "owner" of an object allocated in a method is the stack itself, not the value of `self`. Also note that you cannot place `__strong` (or `__weak`) object pointers into a C struct under ARC, you must use `__unsafe_unretained` and manage the memory explicitly (e.g. with some non-ARC code or with `CFRetain()`/`CFRelease()`).

Comment: Filed <rdar://problem/10798342> asking the compiler to warn/error on this pattern.

Comment: Or you can use Objective-C++, which supports ARC pointers in structs.  (They will be non-POD structs if you put ARC pointers in them.)

Comment: @robmayoff: True, although it's not really a struct at that point, it's a class (since ARC will synthesize a non-trivial destructor).

Comment: @robmayoff good point, but the cocos2d code would have to fundamentally change if I used ObjC++, and I don't have time to deal with that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The crash is because you're casting malloc'd memory to a C array of objects. The moment you try to assign to one of the slots, ARC will release the previous value, which will be garbage memory. Try using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to get zeroed memory and it should work.

Note that your `realloc()` call will also not zero-fill any new memory that's allocated, so if you need the `realloc()` then you may want to be using a temporary `void*` pointer that you then zero-fill manually before assigning to your object array.

Comment: dang. subtle. you really have to know a lot about retain/release/C to use ARC in this instance.

Comment: @nielsbot: As long as you stick to Obj-C you shouldn't have a problem. This sort of thing only crops up when trying to combine basic C stuff (like `malloc()`) with ARC.

Comment: also, if the malloc'd array is just for temporary storage of `id`'s for the scope of the function couldn't you use `(__unsafe_unretained MYID*)` instead of `(MYID*)`?

Comment: @nielsbot: I admit I'm not quite sure what ARC does if you alloc/init an object and assign it to an `__unsafe_unretained` slot. I think it ignores those references entirely, so it'll probably release the object. But using `__autoreleasing` would probably work. Although if you're using ARC then you might want to preserve the explicit lifetime semantics. I know I personally would just make sure the memory is zero-filled if I needed to use this idiom.

Comment: @nielsbot the problem is, it isn't temporary storage, it is using strong objects for a reason, it is an array which manages things about nodes (children, layers, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

The `malloc` function does not zero the memory it allocates.  The memory can contain random garbage.

From the [Clang Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.semantics) guide, section 4.2:

> For `__strong` objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, **the old pointee is released**.

So what's probably happening here is `malloc` is returning memory that contains random non-zero values.  ARC tries to use that random value as a pointer to an object and release it, but it's not a valid object pointer.  Crash.