# Making older files compatible for ARC iOS

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

In order to make older files capable to compiled under ARC, set the switch    -fno-objc-arc 
under Build phase.

But only .m files listed which I can add -fno-objc-arc.

but I have some .h files that caused ARC errors too. I need to set that switch to those .h files. but I don't see them under Build phase.

So, how do I set the switch for the .h files?

Here's a sample of .h file

```
\
__object__=__array__->arr[0]; for(NSUInteger i=0, num=__array__->num; i<num; i++,   __object__=__array__->arr[i])   \


typedef struct ccArray {
    NSUInteger num, max;
    id *arr;
} ccArray;

/** Allocates and initializes a new array with specified capacity */
static inline ccArray* ccArrayNew(NSUInteger capacity) {
    if (capacity == 0)
            capacity = 1; 

    ccArray *arr = (ccArray*)malloc( sizeof(ccArray) );
    arr->num = 0;
    arr->arr =  (id*) malloc( capacity * sizeof(id) );
    arr->max = capacity;

    return arr;
}

 static inline void ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(ccArray *arr);

 /** Frees array after removing all remaining objects. Silently ignores nil arr. */
 static inline void ccArrayFree(ccArray *arr)
{
    if( arr == nil ) return;

    ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(arr);

    free(arr->arr);
    free(arr);
 }

 /** Doubles array capacity */
  static inline void ccArrayDoubleCapacity(ccArray *arr)
 {
    arr->max *= 2;
    id *newArr = (id *)realloc( arr->arr, arr->max * sizeof(id) );
    // will fail when there's not enough memory
     NSCAssert(newArr != NULL, @"ccArrayDoubleCapacity failed. Not enough memory");
    arr->arr = newArr;
}

  /** Increases array capacity such that max >= num + extra. */
   static inline void ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(ccArray *arr, NSUInteger extra)
 {
        while (arr->max < arr->num + extra)
            ccArrayDoubleCapacity(arr);
}

/** shrinks the array so the memory footprint corresponds with the number of items */
static inline void ccArrayShrink(ccArray *arr)
{
NSUInteger newSize;

    //only resize when necessary
    if (arr->max > arr->num && !(arr->num==0 && arr->max==1))
    {
            if (arr->num!=0) 
            {
                    newSize=arr->num;
                    arr->max=arr->num; 
            }
            else 
            {//minimum capacity of 1, with 0 elements the array would be free'd by realloc
                    newSize=1;
                    arr->max=1;
            }

            arr->arr = (id*) realloc(arr->arr,newSize * sizeof(id) );
            NSCAssert(arr->arr!=NULL,@"could not reallocate the memory");
    }
}
```

(id*) causing the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have ARC errors in the .h files if the .m has the -fno-objc-arc flag.

Comment: there are some .h files have no corresponding .m files.

Comment: Even if they have no .m files with a matching name, I would expect they need an #include/#import into a real source file to be part of the compilation.  No?

Comment: well, it's another B.h file imported that A.h file that has the ARC issue. I put the switch on the B.m file.

Comment: I'am not sure if this is really related, but take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308090/id-array-member-instance-under-arc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you split the .h file into an .h/.m pair of files? That way, you can put the method bodies in the .m file, compile it with `-fno-objc-arc`, and include the .h file at will.